# self.navigationController return nil

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, nstimer

In my app I had timer, each 0.3 second it's call a function, and when the timer pass 1min, I should pop to the prvious view controller.

```
updateProgressTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.3, target: self, selector: #selector(TaskDetailsViewController.updateProgress), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

I enter to timer view controller like this:

```
if let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("task-details-viewController")  as? TaskDetailsViewController {


        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

    }
```

and exit the controller after pass 60 min like this:

```
self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

sometimes the self.navigationController is return nil !!

the function that the timer called like this:

```
 func updateProgress() {

    if let time =  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("ProgressTimeValue") as? NSDate {

        if NSDate().secondsFrom(time) > 60 {

                self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

            }

        }
        else {
            let progressvalue = (NSDate().secondsFrom(time))/60
            circularProgress?.progress = progressvalue
            timerLabel.text = Int(NSDate().secondsFrom(time)).description
        }

    }

}
```

so after the 1min pass the timer's viewcontroller didn't pop to the previous one because the self.navigationController is nil !!!

is that because of the timer? or what?

Comment: Is your view controller embedded in a navigation controller?

Comment: @WMios yes sure

Comment: are you using the `UINavigationControllerDelegate`?